# Bulk emails with Mandrill

Tags: php, api, mailchimp, mandrill

I am considering implementing Mandrill for a fully customised email component and have 1 quick question if I may as I can’t find the answer in any of the documentation:

Using the Mandrill API, if I send a **single** request to the API with the preserve_recipients option set to false and the async option set to true with a **single** array with 750 recipients in it, will Mandrill send 1 email with 750 recipients hidden from each other or will it que it and send 750 individual emails?

I would prefer the latter but I am trying to save server time at my end by making 750 API calls to send individual emails when Mandrill’s server already does this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard back from Mandrill on this and this is what they said:

> You're correct that it would send 750 separate / individual emails

I am still yet to test it but it looks promising.

Just in case anyone else out there had the same question.

Lee